# a continuous function $f$ can in fact continuously deformed (homotopy) into an arbitrary close $C^{\infty}$-function

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Show that a continuous function $f$ can in fact continuously deformed (homotopy) into an arbitrary close $C^{\infty}$-function : There exist a continuous function ("homotopy")$ H:IxI \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  s.t $H(t,0)=f(t) ,t\in I $ and s.t $H(.,s)$ is a class of $C^{\infty}$ for each fixed s, $0<s\leq1$ by uniform continuity (!) of $H$ , $H(.,s)$ will be arbitrarily close to $f=H(.,0)$ provided s is sufficiently small.
$\textbf{I have a hint for this to solve as given}$

Prove this by analyzing the known proof with the polynomial kernel $(1-x^2)^{n}$. The integer exponents n are used to obtain a $\textbf{discrete}$ approximation ( by polynomials ) . How to get a continuous approximation instead ( not necessarily with polynomials )

Please if someone can give me an idea to do this problem I will be very Thankful for this kind response

Comment: Let $n\in\mathbb{R}$. Does that work?

Comment: I didn't  get what does mean by$ \n\in \mathbb{R}$ can you elaborate  it more?

Comment: This is proved in T. Tom Dieck's book "Algebraic Topology" as Theorem 15.8.1.

Comment: replace $(1-x^2)^n$ with $\exp(s\ln(1-x^2))$ or so

Comment: @Tyrone  thanks for giving me the reference  I see that proof

Comment: @Tyrone  can you explain  that how this theorem coincide  with the given above statement  in my question,  intact I am pioneer in that so I will be very thankful if you will explain in some detail for me

Comment: The hint is from the proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem from baby Rudin.  The idea is if you convolve a continuous function with a smooth function, you get a smooth function. Now find a family of smooth functions where convolving with them converges to the identity.

Comment: Thanks for giving  me hints.  These hints are helping  me  a lot but I am little bit confuse about the concept of convolution  . Can you elaborate  it more.  Thanks  in anticipation  